# What is the max value of cpp_dec_float from Boost library in C++?

Tags: c++, boost

I am wondering what value causes cpp_dec_float to overflow. I tried gamma function of 10 million and a very large number can still be stored. However, gamma of 11 million cannot be stored.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float<insert_digits_here>>::max()` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk You keep providing solutions in the comments section. Please stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::max()` function to find the maximum value it can store (See also [the boost docs on multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/use_multiprecision.html) and [on numeric_limits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/limits/constants.html)). As an example for `cpp_dec_float_50`:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;
int main() {
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_50>::digits10);
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_50>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

As for what causes overflow specifically, you may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727896/boostmultiprecisioncpp-dec-float-50-overflow-checking) of interest.